# node: print image from url to command line

Tags: node.js, command-line

I am scraping a web site and building a list of objects, one of which is a URL for an image associated with that object.

I'm wondering if there is a way to print the image from the URL to the command line. I have found the [Terminal Image](https://github.com/sindresorhus/terminal-image) library, but it only works with local files. Is my only option to save the image at the URL to a local file and then print that?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Terminal Image readme](https://github.com/sindresorhus/terminal-image#display-a-remote-image):

```
import terminalImage from 'terminal-image'
import got from 'got'

const body = await got('https://sindresorhus.com/unicorn').buffer()
console.log(await terminalImage.buffer(body))
```

The point is **terminalImage** can be used with files paths and buffers aswell.
You don't have to use the **got** library, you can use whatever library you desire to get your images (**axios**, **http**, etc).
You only need to store your image in a variable **as a buffer** to use the **terminalImage.buffer** method.